# ERROR extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry: Error instantiating extensions registry for functions

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I've got an error while I was running the jasperreport. It said that `ERROR extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry: Error instantiating extensions registry for functions`. When I check about the library that used, there's no file `net.sf.jasperreports.functions.FunctionsRegistryFactory` inside the jasperreport.functions-5.6.0.jar. Please help me, because of this, I am not able to get my display of reports. Thank you